# How does an electron spin through 720 degrees for it's marked side to come back to view?

Tags: quantum-spin

I have read that it can be proven experimentally and it occurs to all fermions.

Comment: One does not simply "mark" an electron. I assume you're talking about [$SU(2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#n_.3D_2) being the double cover of $SO(3)$.

Comment: This is [easily answered by a search of this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=spinor+720), though to be fair you need to know the electron is a [spinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) to know what to search for.